# WatchDog Timer In Linux

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, embedded-linux

I want to do software wathdog timer using timer interrupt in linux. How can i generate timer interrupt in linux?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use timer interrupts, use signals, and especially `SIGALRM`.
You can use the function [alarm()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) to ask for a timeout. if you want usec granularity you can use [ualarm()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ualarm).
Once the timeout has reached it will call a Callback function you defined before.

Here's an example code:

```
#include <signal.h>

void watchdog(int sig) 
{
  printf("Pet the dog\r\n");
  /* reset the timer so we get called again in 5 seconds */
  alarm(5);
}


/* start the timer - we want to wake up in 5 seconds */
int main()
{
  /* set up our signal handler to catch SIGALRM */
  signal(SIGALRM, watchdog);
  alarm(5);
  while (true) 
   ;
}
```

You have few other options for implementing a watchdog:

1. Write / Use a kernel driver, which actually works as a watchdog, applying a hard reset to the device if the dog is not pet (or kicked)
2. Use an [watchdog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog), an interesting implementation of a software watchdog daemon.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I want implement in accurate milliseconds delay. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts do not exist at the application level (only the kernel manages them, and indeed it is getting a lot of timer interrupts already). You can have signals, timers, and delaying syscalls (notably `poll` or `nanosleep`). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Read first the [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) man page. Then [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html), [setitimer(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html), [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) etc....

Some kernels can also be configured to have watchdog timers...